# ORA - 00972 : identifier too long

Tags: oracle

I am getting error (ORA - 00972 : identifier too long)  while creating the view.

Please find the view statement.

```
create or replace view ELVW_ATM_REC_HANDOFF_1   
(Rectype
    ,Recseq
    ,Record_Type
    ,Record_Sequence
    ,MESSAGE_TYPE
    ,PAN
    ,PROCESSING_CODE
    ,TRANSACTION_AMOUNT
    ,TRANSACTION_CURRENCY_CODE
    ,SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT
    ,SETTLEMENT_CURRENCY_CODE
    ,Billing_AMOUNT
    ,Billing_CURRENCY_CODE
    ,Transaction_DATE
    ,Settlement_Date
    ,TRACE
    ,REFERENCE_NUMBER
    ,Switch_Log_ID
    ,AUTHORIZATION_NUMBER
    ,RESPONSE_CODE
    ,Host_Error_Code
    ,TERMINAL_ID
    ,Acceptor_ID
    ,ACQUIRING_INSTITUTION_CODE
    ,REV_FLAG
    ,Original_Trace_Number
    ,From_Account
    ,To_Account) 

as
select * from    


(select 'FT'
    ,'count'
    ,'DT'
    ,rownum
    ,msg_type
    ,pan,proc_code
    ,txn_amt
    ,txn_ccy_code
    ,setl_amt
    ,setl_ccy_code
    ,bill_amt
    ,bill_ccy_code
    ,trans_dt_time
    ,setl_date
    ,stan,trn_ref_no
    ,'iso field 60'
    ,'isofield 38'
    ,resp_code
    ,error_code
    ,term_id
    ,'ISOmessage42'
    ,acq_ins_id
    ,decode(substr(msg_type,1,1),4,reverse(msg_type),msg_type)
    ,'ISOfield90'
    ,from_acc
    ,to_acc 
    from swtb_txn_log)
```

It seems error occurs at the decode function. if i comment it. its working fine. Please find the below code

```
create or replace view ELVW_ATM_REC_HANDOFF_1(Rectype,Recseq,Record_Type,Record_Sequence,MESSAGE_TYPE,PAN,PROCESSING_CODE,TRANSACTION_AMOUNT,TRANSACTION_CURRENCY_CODE,SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT,SETTLEMENT_CURRENCY_CODE,Billing_AMOUNT,Billing_CURRENCY_CODE,Transaction_DATE,/*Transaction_TIME,*/Settlement_Date,TRACE,REFERENCE_NUMBER,Switch_Log_ID,AUTHORIZATION_NUMBER,RESPONSE_CODE,Host_Error_Code,TERMINAL_ID,Acceptor_ID,ACQUIRING_INSTITUTION_CODE,/*REV_FLAG,*/Original_Trace_Number,From_Account,To_Account) as
select * from (select 'FT','count','DT',rownum,msg_type,pan,proc_code,txn_amt,txn_ccy_code,setl_amt,setl_ccy_code,bill_amt,bill_ccy_code,trans_dt_time,/*trans_dt_time,*/setl_date,stan,trn_ref_no,'iso field 60',
'isofield 38',resp_code,error_code,term_id,'ISOmessage42',acq_ins_id,/*decode(substr(msg_type,1,1),4,reverse(msg_type),msg_type),*/'ISOfield90',from_acc,to_acc from swtb_txn_log)
```

I have checked the length of the column name. Its less than 30 characters. Looking forward for your help.

Comment: Identifier too long? Code sample too long more like. If you want people to help you, you shoudl really make more of an effort to format your question so it's readable.  Perhaps if you had laid out your code more clearly you would have been able to spot the problem instead of asking us to spot it.

Comment: Well the code is very hard to read as you have it posted but a guess would be that since you are creating a view oracle does not automatically truncate the column name and you would need to give that column name an alias but that is just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

Try giving an alias (that is shorter than 30 characters) to the `DECODE` function.

Example:

```
DECODE( ...stuff... ) MYALIAS
```

Comment: That would be my suggestion also.

Answer (score 1):

True, all of the column names in the view spec are less than thirty characters.

Howver, your view includes a inline query:

```
select * from ( select ...
```

This may be the problem.  Because it may be trying to work out at identifier for DECODE() statement at that intermediate point.  I say "may" because I can't reproduce this on my 10g box: defining column names for the view solves the ORA-01948.

Regardless, you can fix the problem simply by giving your DECODE() column an alias which is of an acceptable length.